# Deployed wordpress is now showing basic auth popup instead of login page for wp-admin

Tags: authentication, wordpress

I have a wordpress website that hasn't been logged into for awhile, and it appears some auto-update change happened. The wp-admin login screen is now blocked by a basic auth popup. The admin and user credentials we thought were still good are no longer working, and because this pop-up blocks the load of the login page there's no way to reset a password.

Anyone else seen a wordpress update force a basic-auth window to replace the login page? I've seen some notes about fixing it via an .htaccess file but there isn't one in place, so I'm not even sure what caused this change.

Comment: Questions about WordPress are not within scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound normal and Wordpress updates do not automatically install what you just described.

If you are seeing an additional popup when you try to load your wp-admin screen, chances are your host added in that security measure. Send a ticket to your host and there is a 99% chance they will be able to advise you.

Also, check your emails, I had that experience before where a host added that extra security measure, and they simply sent an email informing clients about that and the login credentials. It is not the same login credentials as your actual wp-admin too, and that is why you are unable to access or get past it.